# jQuery 'on()' command

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, propagation

So, i wondered, why this code doesn't work properly, and what can i do, to prevent such a behaviour:
If I would need to prevent event propagation of parent, whilst particular child got clicked, i used `method 1`, but it seems not to be working, but `method 2` is working fine though.

```js
//method 1
$(document).on({
  click: function(e) {
    console.log('clicked!');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}, '.hax');
//method 2
/*$('.hax').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
 });*/
//uncommenting will prevent event propagation
```

```css
.hax {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper' onclick='alert("hello")'>
  <div class='hax'>hax!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you use onclick in 1st div <div class='wrapper' ?
$(document).on({
  click: function(e) {
   alert("hello");
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
}, '.wrapper');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1** Is using *event delegatio*n ,so in it event is not directly bind with the element , its bound with the parent ,So in your case the parent is document . in this the case whatever event will be fired for that particular element it will be tracked down from the DOM tree and will execute the parent call before. In your case it will first call the `alert` from parent .

In **method 2** - event is directly bound with the element , The event of parent will still got fired unless you prevent that in the handler but since the handler is bound to the target , you will not face any other action(alert in your case)

Get better Idea of
[Event Delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation)

Comment: Adding to this you can study "Additional Notes" section in http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by method 1, which can be created the following way too:

```
$(document).on('click', '.hax', function (e) {
    console.log('clicked!');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
 });
```

For clarifying event delegation briefly:

> Understanding how events propagate is an important factor in being able to leverage Event Delegation. *Any time one of our anchor tags is clicked*, **a click event is fired for that anchor, and then bubbles up the DOM tree**(Up to DOM top), triggering **each of its parent** click event handlers.

It does not mean you can't achieve your goal here with this method, but in order to make it work, you can create a middle parent for `div.hax` which is descendant of `div.wrapper`. I mean:

```
<div class='wrapper' onclick='alert("hello")'>
    <div id="stopHere">
        <div class='hax'>hax!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, we can use method 1, but we only need to stop `event propagation` / `event delegation` before it reach `div.wrapper`. Thus in our newly added `div#stopHere`:

```
$("div#stopHere").on('click', '.hax', function (e) {
    console.log('clicked!');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, now it's clear for me. Although, the solution is a little bit overengineering, as for me. Still, I do apreciate your participation `=)`